# does galera setup cause db down and slower db read?

Tags: mysql, django, mariadb, database-replication, multi-master-replication

recently I realized after I setup master to master replication using galera, my db seems to be loading slower than usual.

Also, sometimes it cannot be connected.

I am currently using django and I have it setup that if main DB cannot be connected while making a request, then use the second db until the main DB is back online.  I will receive an email if the DB cannot be connected while making a request.

This would happen randomly and sometimes when I get the email, then right away I login into mariadb to check its status...it's actually actively running.

As for db seems to be loading slower than usual is because, when I go into the django admin dashboard, usually it just boom when I check any records or go into any model but now it'll LOAD...........then show.

I can barely find out any reason for this, does any one have any idea or which / where log I can setup for a more thorough check?

Thanks in advance for any advices.

Comment: Are you using `LOAD DATA`?  How much data?  How far apart (in milliseconds) are the Galera nodes?  Is the `LOAD` slow, or is the data being slow to reach the other nodes?  Etc.

Comment: @RickJames how can I check these? I am really new into this :|